# Archivelog redundancy

Tags: oracle, archive

I need to enable archivelog. But sometimes database can't connect archivelog destination (NFS disk) and shutdowns. I can set two archivelog destinations and one of them is not NFS disk (local disk).

How can I configure, if database can't connect to NFS disk (dest1), to just write on local disk (dest2) and continue to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Ideally you should use reliable storage for your archivelog destination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ALTERNATE` attribute in second archive log destination.

> #### ALTERNATE
>
> Specifies an alternate archiving destination to be used when the original destination fails.

Example:

```
LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1='LOCATION=/disk1 MANDATORY ALTERNATE=LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_2'
LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_STATE_1=ENABLE
LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_2='LOCATION=/disk2 MANDATORY'
LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_STATE_2=ALTERNATE
```

Reference:
[LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n Parameter Attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28294/log_arch_dest_param.htm#i91817)